# ffplay won't play videos in Documents subfolders, firejail configuration issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg, firejail

I have a subfolder of ~/Documents where I want to store various videos (.mp4 files). I don't particularly want to move them to the ~/Videos folder because they contain other files which are not videos.

I have firejail active (version 0.9.66). When attempting to play one of these videos (with ffplay or the Video Player) I get a message "No such file or directory" however the file does in fact exist, and I have permissions to read it. Also, I can use ffmpeg to make a copy of the file, no problems.

The exact same video plays correctly when moved/copied to my home folder, so there is not an issue per se with the video or ffplay.

I am guessing I need some sort of amendment to my firejail configuration to permit videos to play but I can't work out what it is.

Inside the file `/etc/firejail/ffmpeg.profile` I added a line (below) which didn't help:

```
noblacklist ${MUSIC}
noblacklist ${VIDEOS}
nowhitelist ${HOME}/Documents    <--  added this line
```

I can't see offhand what else to do. Is there a different configuration I need? Do I need to reload the configuration somehow?

My Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 0):

The amended (third line below) line should have read `noblacklist`.

In the file `/etc/firejail/ffmpeg.profile`.

Add the third line below after the other `noblacklist` lines:

```
noblacklist ${MUSIC}
noblacklist ${VIDEOS}
noblacklist ${HOME}/Documents
```

That fixed the issue. I'm kind-of embarrased to have solved it after posting this, but I'll leave this question here in case it helps someone else. Or you can vote to close it. :)

---

> I still have the problem with the "Videos" player.

It seems the default video player is called "totem". Adding the above line to the `totem.profile` file didn't help, however this did:

In the file `/etc/firejail/whitelist-player-common.inc` add the line

```
whitelist ${HOME}/Documents
```

Comment: I still have the problem with the "Videos" player. What is that app's "real" name - that I can amend the firejail configuration for?